# Numpy split a matrix and put the blocks in a diagonal matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, split

Good morning, I'm writing a little project in Python (I'm still learning the language) and I'm a bit stuck. I have a numpy array made like this:

```
x1 0 0 0 0
x1 x1 0 0 0
x1 x1 x1 0 0
x1 x1 x1 x1 0
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1
...
x x x x x
y y y y y
x2 0 0 0 0
x2 x2 0 0 0
x2 x2 x2 0 0
x2 x2 x2 x2 0
x2 x2 x2 x2 x2
...
```

And so on. Every "section" delimited by a specific value "y" is shorter than the previous by 5 rows; the first section is, of course, the longest one. All the "x" are floats, their value is not known to me a priori, I have called them "x1" and "x2" for clarity.
My objective is to obtain a triangular matrix that puts side by side all the blocks, for example:

```
x1 
x1 x1  
x1 x1 x1 
x1 x1 x1 x1 
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1 x2
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1 x2 x2 
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1 x2 x2 x2
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1 x2 x2 x2 x2
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1 x2 x2 x2 x2 x2
...
x1 x1 x1 x1 x1 x2 x2 x2 x2 x2 x3 x3 x3 x3 x3 x4 x4 x4 x4 x4 ...xN xN xN xN xN
```

In other words I take the "x2" block and put it near the block "x1" but 5 rows unders; I do the same with "x3" with respect to "x2" and so until the matrix is over.
I was thinking about the best "pythonic" way to do so.
One that I thought about might consist in splitting the array (np.split) when the value "y" occurs, put the block side by side and then put down the "x2...xN" columns manually.
Otherwise the task might be done using some nested for loops putting every element singularly in the right spot.
Any suggestion about how to proceed?
Thanks in advance and sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share your code. Also, are you missing a line `x1 x1 x1 x1 x1` (i.e. 5x `x1 `) in that example? Or did you intentionally jump from 4x `x1` to 5x `x1` followed by an `x2`?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake in the example and edited it. At the moment I did not try anything, I have done this in MATLAB with nested for loops and wanted to "translate" the script in python. I was just thinking about the best way to do it using the functionalities of numpy.

Comment: SO is not a place to come and ask people to write your code for free - it is expected you at least make an effort to do it yourself and come on here to ask about specific problems you run in. Read a basic tutorial on `numpy`, or some documentation and give it a shot, ask questions about problems later.

Comment: But I don't want some code, I want just to discuss, as a learner, the procedure and then write my own code using the different approaches; I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. I expected a reply using just words, like the two examples that I made a the end. Sorry again.

Comment: Grismar is right, the site encourages to share your code, but not as a school teacher who wants you to try and fail before you get the actual answer... it is just that most of the time a question like "how do I implement this feature?" tends to be too broad to be answered in a single post. SO's ultimate mission is to be a sort of encyclopedia of coding, and it is a policy to have each post as simple and concise as possible.

Comment: And if you provide your code, most of the time it is a lot easier to explain what you are trying to do and in what specific step you are stuck. That way other users can give better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just can just loop through the array and store the last entry from each block. For the next block, prepend the previous last entry.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(
[
[1,0,0,0,0], 
[1,2,0,0,0], 
[1,2,3,0,0], 
[1,2,3,4,0], 
[1,2,3,4,5], 
[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
[6,0,0,0, 0], 
[6,7,0,0, 0], 
[6,7,8,0, 0], 
[6,7,8,9, 0], 
[6,7,8,9,10], 
[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
])


lst = []
lstprev = []
tmp = []
for r in arr:
   if r[0] == -1:
      lstprev.extend(tmp)
      continue
   tmp = [v for v in r if v != 0]
   lst.append(lstprev + tmp)
   print(lstprev + tmp)
```

Output

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new arrays with each unique value (`x1, x2, ..., xn`) and stack them horizontally, then get the lower triangular matrix from that stacked array.

```
import numpy as np

def full_stack_tril(arr: np.ndarray, y: int, delta_rows: int):
    _, idx = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_index=True)
    values = arr[(np.sort(idx), 0)]
    values = np.delete(values, np.where(values==y))
    
    n = arr.shape[0] - values.shape[0] + 1 # number of rows in final array
    result = np.hstack(
        [np.full((n, arr.shape[1] - i * delta_rows), x)
            for i, x in enumerate(values)]
    )
    result = np.tril(result)
    return result

# parameters
y = -1 
delta_rows = 2
# sample with values that should not be sorted
# i.e. the order should be preserved
# each section has delta_rows less rows than the previous one
arr = np.array([
    [4.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [4.1, 4.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 0.0, 0.0],
    [4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 0.0],
    [4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1],
    [y, y, y, y, y],
    [3.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [3.2, 3.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 0.0, 0.0],
    [y, y, y, y, y],
    [3.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
])

result = full_stack_tril(arr, y, delta_rows)
```

Output

```
[[4.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 4.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 3.2 0.  0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 3.2 3.2 0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 3.2 3.2 3.2 0. ]
 [4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.8]]
```

Notice how the result is padded with zeros, since the standard `ndarray` does not support jagged shapes.